# Strapi - GraphQL - Issue on sorting and paginating

Tags: sorting, next.js, graphql, pagination, strapi

I’ve had an issue using Strapi when I try to combine sorting and pagination on my GraphQL requests from a NextJS front. Basically, I am trying to query the backend to fetch all records sorted by creation date from the newest to the latest, and THEN paginate them.

My issue is : the pagination occurs BEFORE the sorting. Example :

If I have 4 docs like so :

```
     - Document 1
     - Document 2
     - Document 3
     - Document 4
```

I want them sorted by date and 2 by page, which would give me :

```
    Page 1
     - Document 4
     - Document 3
    Page 2
     - Document 2
     - Document 1
```

But I have this instead :

```
    Page 1
     - Document 2
     - Document 1
    Page 2
     - Document 4
     - Document 3
```

My query looks like this :

```
query getDocuments {
documents (
  sort:"updatedAt:asc"
  pagination: {page: ${page}, pageSize: 10}
){
  meta {pagination {total page pageCount}}
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        name
        category
        updatedAt
        creator {data {attributes {username}}}
      }
    }
}
}
```

It paginates first, then sorts. Did you observe this behavior ? Is it intended ? Is it GraphQL itself working this way or Strapi ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess you have to do sort by desc

Comment: generally sorting occurs 1st after that pagination will happen. I have used many graphql wrappers in most of them it is happening like this only. Since It will violates the purpose of wrapper & sorting over the table.

Comment: If this is still happening like firstly it was fetching the data and then sorting is applied . 1st you can join strapi slack/discord raise the issue with them or create a clever way to fetch data by date or time wise. (add an calendar for the user, where they can see last 15 mins data ,  1 month data like wise)